# Debugging memory leak in compact framework 2.0

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, compact-framework

I'm working with a windows mobile application, running compact framework 2 and vb.net code. Having a need to sync the application every determined-period of time, I use system.threading.timer to set a predefined timer for each sync process.

The issue is one, my memory is building fast, reaching 24 MB rapidly and the app crush due to OutOfMemoryException.

I understood that compact framework's GC is not good at best, and has only 2MB of gc heap, I use 4 MB each sync and the gc cleans only 2MB, as it's capabilities.

I tried to use Performance Monitor tool of the build in compact framework 2.0 but it only provided me with the object that are "still alive" and are not cleaned or disposed with no real notion of what's going on in each part of the app.

Is there any efficient way of monitoring memory leaks in compact framework 2.0?
One that will guide me through which method is causing the issue or which part of the code is problematic?

Or in the other way, any helpful ways to manage my memory in a more, let's say, efficient way as I have only 32MB of free ram space which is a very narrow ail here.

Comment: From my point of view, a memory leak is when you allocate an object and do not free (Dispose and set to Null) it after use. I would dump the memory state before and after each function that is suspect. After that go into the function that does not release memory and look for objects that are not freed. Remember that an object is not disposed automatically as long as a reference to that object exists in the process.

Comment: have a look at NETCF CLR Profiler avalible in [Compact Framework Power Toys](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442) it will show how many of each object are being created and what methods are creating your objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sceptical that this issue relates to an actual memory leak.

Attach your device and start a debugging session and monitor your stack trace & number of threads in the thread dropdown in Visual Studio. I suspect you are spinning up too many threads without disposing the old ones or you have a circular call to a function or subroutine that is growing your stack trace too large - you tend to find on small devices that you run out of memory before you get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using an internal data base we created for the application, we came to the conclusion that working purely on XML documents is not smart in this case, as we have more then 300 clients to handle withing the XML file. 
we ended up having to parse an XML file for 19,000 rows which was absurd considering the platform we use, which only gives us a space of 24MB to use.

We created an internal DB that will handle the internal application business and DAL logic.

This way we don't have to work with huge XML files and thus, can work around the performance issue we had.